# Create 2D array with "new"?

Tags: c++

I want to create a 2D array like the following.

```
char **dog = new char[480][640];
```

But it errors:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'char (*)[640]' to 'char ** '
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

what do I need to do using "new"?  (not using calloc, malloc or `char dog[480][640];`)

Comment: `char (*p)[640] = new char[480][640];` Note that a 2D array of `T` is not the same as an array of pointers to arrays of `T`. Oh, and rather use `std::vector` than raw `new`. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Yeah, `std::vector<std::array<char, 640> > dog(480);`

Comment: @Mooing Duck: that covers 640x350 and 640x480 resolutions, but it does look a bit odd to mix `vector` and `array` that way. I think I'd use just `vector` all the way, forget about the micro-optimization possible with `array`, and as an added bonus get code that works with more current compilers. Cheers,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
char **dog = new char *[480];
for (int i = 0; i < 480; i++)
    dog[i] = new char[640];
```

And the same when deleting, but then the loop first.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get memory from heap, you can use it this way:

```
// declaration
char *dog = new char[640*480];

// usage
dog[first_index * 640 + second_index] = 'a';

// deletion
delete[] dog;
```

Comment: I think an indexing scheme like this is almost always preferable to handling 2d arrays directly.

Comment: how much more overhead is there in a 2D array vs 1D array? does it slow things down?

Comment: @jdl: shouldn't be any overhead, but this is faster for some things, and more error-prone in others.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a pointer to a pointer by using `**`. I'm not sure you want that, you probably want a normal pointer (`*`).